# Android MapView load location from searchView

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

Is it possible in mapView to load a marker when the user clicks a button or submits a search in searchView. I am having trouble getting marker locations to show when the user submits data. When the user submits the info it pulls the lat and long but does not update the position from the view model immediately.

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private static final String TAG = "SearchFragment";

private SearchViewModel searchViewModel;
private LatLng location;
private Marker marker;

//UI
private MapView mapView;
private SearchView searchView;
private TextView cityTv, countryTv, regionTv, ispTv, timezoneTv, postalTv, countryCallingCodeTv;

private static final String MAPVIEW_BUNDLE = "MAPVIEW_BUNDLE";


public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: ");
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_searchview);
    cityTv = view.findViewById(R.id.city_input_textview);
    countryTv = view.findViewById(R.id.country_input_textview);
    regionTv = view.findViewById(R.id.region_input_textview);
    ispTv = view.findViewById(R.id.isp_input_textview);
    timezoneTv = view.findViewById(R.id.timezone_input_textview);
    postalTv = view.findViewById(R.id.postal_input_textview);
    countryCallingCodeTv = view.findViewById(R.id.countrycallingcode_input_textview);


    Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE);
    }
    mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.location_mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);


    searchViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SearchViewModel.class);


    searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            searchView.setIconified(false);
            //returns result from search view
            getSearchViewResults(view);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE);
    if (mapViewBundle == null) {
        mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
        outState.putBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE, mapViewBundle);
    }
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
}


//retrieves the search results from searchView and passes information to searchviewmodel
public void getSearchViewResults(final View view) {
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit: ");

            //TODO: add input validation to make sure addres is correct
            //TODO: if incorrect display toast message saying input is invalid
            searchViewModel.getIpAddress(query);
            //observer to observe data change and display search results in textview
            observeSearchView();
            mapView.getMapAsync(SearchFragment.this);


            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}


private void observeSearchView() {

    searchViewModel.getIpLocation().observe(SearchFragment.this, new Observer<IPLocation>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(IPLocation ipLocation) {
            cityTv.setText(ipLocation.getCity());
            countryTv.setText(ipLocation.getCountry());
            regionTv.setText(ipLocation.getRegion());
            ispTv.setText(ipLocation.getOrg());
            timezoneTv.setText(ipLocation.getTimezone());
            countryCallingCodeTv.setText(ipLocation.getCountryCallingCode());
            postalTv.setText(ipLocation.getPostal());
            location = new LatLng(ipLocation.getLatitude(), ipLocation.getLongitude());

            //  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Lat: " + location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
}


//displays the lat/lon of entered address
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: ");


    //test adds marker in sydney and moves the camera to location
    if (searchViewModel.getResult()) {


        try {

            marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Location"));
            marker.setPosition(location);
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
            googleMap.getMinZoomLevel();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Exception: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "FALSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume: map ");
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart: map");
    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop: map");
    super.onStop();
    mapView.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause: map ");
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: map");
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}





public class SearchViewModel extends ViewModel {
private static final String TAG = "SearchViewModel";

private Boolean result = false;
private String input;
private ArrayList<IPLocation> ipLocationsList;
private MutableLiveData<IPLocation> ipLocation;
private MutableLiveData<Double> latResult = new MutableLiveData<>();
private MutableLiveData<Double> lonResult = new MutableLiveData<>();


public SearchViewModel() {
    Log.d(TAG, "SearchViewModel: ");
    ipLocation = new MutableLiveData<>();
    ipLocationsList = new ArrayList<>();


}

public void getIpAddress(String ipAdress) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getInfo: Start");


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final Date dateNow = calendar.getTime();
    final GetDataService[] getDataService = {RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofit()
            .create(GetDataService.class)};

    Call<IPLocation> call = getDataService[0].getLocationByIP(ipAdress);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<IPLocation>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<IPLocation> call, Response<IPLocation> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Start");
            ipLocation.setValue(new IPLocation(0, response.body().getIp(),
                    response.body().getCity(), response.body().getRegion(),
                    response.body().getRegionCode(), response.body().getCountry(), response.body().getCountryName(),
                    response.body().getContinentCode(), response.body().getInEu(), response.body().getPostal(),
                    response.body().getLatitude(), response.body().getLongitude(), response.body().getTimezone(),
                    response.body().getUtcOffset(), response.body().getCountryCallingCode(), response.body().getCurrency(),
                    response.body().getLanguages(), response.body().getAsn(), response.body().getOrg(), dateNow));


            latResult.setValue(response.body().getLatitude());
            lonResult.setValue(response.body().getLongitude());
            setResult(true);


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<IPLocation> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Fail");


        }

    });


}


public Boolean getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(Boolean result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public MutableLiveData<IPLocation> getIpLocation() {
    return ipLocation;
}

public MutableLiveData<Double> getLatResult() {
    return latResult;
}

public void setLatResult(MutableLiveData<Double> latResult) {
    this.latResult = latResult;
}

public MutableLiveData<Double> getLonResult() {
    return lonResult;
}

public void setLonResult(MutableLiveData<Double> lonResult) {
    this.lonResult = lonResult;
}
```

}

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/location_title_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/location_title"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/location_mapview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="319dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your google map object globally after receiving object from **onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)** callback.

After making an API call and fetching the result, do something like this to your map

```
LatLng latlng = new LatLng(response.body().getLatitude(), response.body().getLongitude());
MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOption();
markerOptions.setPosition(latlng);
markerOptions.setIcon(*PASS_YOUR_BITMAP_FOR_ICON_HERE*);
markerOptions.title("Location")

Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOption);
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
```

Comment: I get it working but I the problem I have is that I have to click the searchview twice to get the marker to move to the new position.

Comment: Few Questions: Why are you adding again and again setOnQueryTextListener on each click? It should be set only once as it will keep observing until your Fragment's onDestroy() is not called once set for the first time.

Comment: Also, you are calling mapView.getMapAsyc() again and again on each result in onQueryTextSubmit(). This is not needed. If you already have a marker set previously, save your marker globally and change its position every time using marker.setLocation(position) instead of calling mapView.getMapAsync() again. And if your marker is not set yet then add you marker on map directly and save it to global variable so that it can be reused later.